# Json object (de)serialization. Typed languages with class hierarchy

Tags: javascript, json, scala, types, jvm

I encountered a problem with JSONs in web client-server application.

**Context:** scala (could be any typed language with inheritance), typescript+angularjs, json representation in NoSql postgresql, same json sent to web client.

How can I add type to json representation to get features such as:

1. describes generics like List
2. enables easy usage of inheritance in javascript/typescript world
3. can be deserialized line by line (like SAX) by json deserializer to get fast transformation with minimum memory used

Adding attribute to object like **{myList: (...) , (...), type: ?? }** interferes with point 3 due to no guarantee of attributes order.

Adding type as attribute name  **List#Integer#: {myList: (...) , (...)}** makes the code ugly on client side due to additional wrapper/prefix everywhere.

How to solve this problem? Maybe somebody knows of Scala json library that already supports types?

Many libraries just assume that you know what type you are loading...

Comment: Take a look at https://avro.apache.org/ and https://github.com/edn-format/edn . They both are not related to JSON, but kinda targeted for dynamic typed reciever, which could have not aprior schema knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Optimised deserializing is needed only on server side. For web client I transform JSON from **List#Integer#: {myList: (...) , (...)} to {myList: (...) , (...), type: "List#Integer#" }**

Adding type node to every object inferfers with frameworks, components i.e.: angular tree accepts only one children container at each node. Drag&drop doesn't work then. Working with flat type attribute is more predictable.